# Ensure SSL all the way to the pod using Google Container Engine Ingress

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a pod that serves HTTPS traffic on 443 using a self-signed certificate with a CN of `app` that matches the service name, `app`. It also serves HTTP on 80.

I also have an Ingress object that exposes the pod externally on `foo.com` and I use `kube-lego` to dynamically fetch and configure a LetsEncrypt certificate for foo.com:

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: kube-lego-gce
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /.well-known/acme-challenge/*
      - backend:
          serviceName: app
          servicePort: 80
        path: /*
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - foo.com
    secretName: app-tls-staging
```

This means there are two levels of SSL. If I set the `servicePort` of the Ingress to 443 to ensure traffic between Google's LB and my pod is encrypted, the endpoint returns `502 Server Error`. Is this because it doesn't know to trust my self-signed cert? Is there a way to specify a CA?

Once I set it back to 80 the Ingress starts working normally again after a few minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is "re-encryption" for Load Balancer <=> cluster traffic. If you see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#future-work), re-encryption is listed as "Future Work".

But I see this feature is merged: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/pull/519/commits

It looks like you can find an [example here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/4c868cf62afa94dda6cc74a3fb92ed77b606eb7b/controllers/gce/examples/backside_https) and it's described as "Backend HTTPS" in this document: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/controllers/gce#backend-https

However today this feature seems to be in alpha, so it may be subject to change and you may need to create an alpha GKE cluster (which is short-lived) to use it.

Comment: Finally had a chance to try this out. It worked without having to create an alpha cluster. Thanks!